# PHP mail send noname file in attachment

Tags: php

I want to send attachment with php `mail` but file after sent in **noname**.

This is my code:

```
if( isset($_FILES['attachment'])) 
{ 

    $from_email    = $_POST["contact_email"]; 
    $recipient_email         = 'mohammad.a1381@gmail.com';

    //Load POST data from HTML form 
    $sender_name    = $_POST["contact_names"]; 
    $sender_phone   = $_POST["contact_phone"]; 
    $reply_to_email = $_POST["contact_email"]; 

    $subject        = 'resome'; //subject for the email 
    $message        = $_POST["contact_message"];

    //Get uploaded file data using $_FILES array 
    $tmp_name    = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name   = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    $size        = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];
    $file_type   = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
    $error       = $_FILES['attachment']['error']; 

    //validate form field for attaching the file 
    if($error > 0) 
    { 
        die('Upload error or No files uploaded'); 
    } 

    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content 
    $handle = fopen($tmp_name, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $size);
    fclose($handle);

    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); 

    $boundary = md5("random");

    //header 
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; // Defining the MIME version 
    $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; // Sender Email 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
    $headers .= "boundary = $boundary\r\n"; //Defining the Boundary 

    //plain text  
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n"; 
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";  
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));  

    //attachment 
    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n"; 
    $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
    $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
    $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
    $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n";  
    $body .= $encoded_content;

    $sentMailResult = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers); 

    if($sentMailResult )  
    { 
       echo "File Sent Successfully."; 
       unlink($name);
    } 
    else
    { 
       die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. 
                    Please go back and try again!"); 
    }
```

Comment: i think here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail#answer-12302354 you got the best answer

Comment: @MichaelMulik I could not fine any special different, could you plz help me to fix it more?

Comment: Make sure that your case is not this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and use a class like https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/ instead of constructing email payloads manually.

Answer (score 1):

I use this my code to send multiple attachments and works fine for me... let's me know is enough for you. I read your code and can be improved by using `file_get_contents` instead `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose`.

About `md5("random")` is not enough safe, I suggest use `md5(uniqid(time()))`, you have encoded the message part in addition to encoded file with `$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message))`, this is not necessary since you are sending plain text, pay attention to terminate properly your **mime boundary** because if used in the wrong sequence may cause incorrect attachment of files to your mail.

There are some other minor fix to apply, you can find them into my code.

`html:`

```
<label for="attachment1">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="attachment1" name="attachment[]" size="35">
<label for="attachment2">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="attachment2" name="attachment[]" size="35">
<label for="attachment3">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="attachment3" name="attachment[]" size="35">
```

`php:`

```
if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name'])) {
  $semi_rand = md5(uniqid(time()));
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
  $headers = "From: " . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($sender_name) . '?=' . " <$from_email>" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($sender_name) . '?=' . " <$reply_to_email>" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_email" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= " Boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
  $datamsg = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}" . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; Charset=\"UTF-8\"" . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  $datamsg .= $message . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  for ($index = 0; $index < count($_FILES['attachment']['name']); $index++) {
    if ($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$index] != "") {
      $file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$index];
      $data_file = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$index])));
      $datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}" . PHP_EOL;
      $datamsg .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Name=\"{$file_name}\"" . PHP_EOL;
      $datamsg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=\"{$file_name}\"" . PHP_EOL;
      $datamsg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $data_file . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
  $datamsg .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
}
if (@mail($recipient_email, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=', $datamsg, $headers, "-f$from_email")) {
  exit("Files Sent Successfully");
} else {
  exit("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!");
}
```

There is no reason for `unlink($name)` since you are **not** uploading files to your server, you are reading the tmp file name from tmp server directory and converting it in base64 (nothing else...), you miss the final `"--$boundary--";` very important to terminate properly the message part and the attachments... `$headers .= "boundary = $boundary`... is not correct because needs a tabulation instead you can write it like `$headers .= " Boundary = $boundary`...

I did a test using my code and with success, I censored my sensible data, all rest is visible and Ok:

```
From - Mon Jun  3 18:17:49 2019
Return-Path: <test@test.com>
Delivered-To: test@test.com
    for <test@test.com>; Mon, 03 Jun 2019 18:17:36 +0200
    ; Mon, 03 Jun 2019 18:17:36 +0200
Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2019 18:17:39 +0200
To: test@test.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UHJvdmE=?=
From: =?UTF-8?B?QWxlc3NhbmRybyBNYXJpbnV6emk=?= <test@test.com>
Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?QWxlc3NhbmRybyBNYXJpbnV6emk=?= <test@test.com>
Return-Path: test@test.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 Boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x2bf07da61d9de3d12f7c30d38eabbf40x"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--==Multipart_Boundary_x2bf07da61d9de3d12f7c30d38eabbf40x
Content-Type: text/plain; Charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Test with attachments...

--==Multipart_Boundary_x2bf07da61d9de3d12f7c30d38eabbf40x
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Name="test.zip"
Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename="test.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

UEsDBBQAAAAIAImAwU7q5x4NDgAAAA4AAAAIAAAAdGVzdC50eHQrycgsVgCiRIWS1OISAFBLAQIf
ABQAAAAIAImAwU7q5x4NDgAAAA4AAAAIACQAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAB0ZXN0LnR4dAoAIAAAAAAA
AQAYALUw9eeCGNUBtTD154IY1QEfNnDlghjVAVBLBQYAAAAAAQABAFoAAAA0AAAAAAA=


--==Multipart_Boundary_x2bf07da61d9de3d12f7c30d38eabbf40x
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Name="this is another test.zip"
Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename="this is another test.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

UEsDBAoAAAAAALuRw04AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAdGhpcyBpcyBhbm90aGVyIHRlc3QudHh0UEsB
Ah8ACgAAAAAAu5HDTgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAJAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAHRoaXMgaXMgYW5vdGhl
ciB0ZXN0LnR4dAoAIAAAAAAAAQAYADFJ3FcnGtUBMUncVyca1QExSdxXJxrVAVBLBQYAAAAAAQAB
AGoAAAA2AAAAAAA=


--==Multipart_Boundary_x2bf07da61d9de3d12f7c30d38eabbf40x--
```

Comment: I changed my code to your code, but still attachment send file without any format file, attachment name is first letter of the word.

Comment: Have you seen in the source generated email?

Comment: Try to send a file of 1 kb and read the source generated email... it's the only way to investigate...

Comment: I did a test and using my php code the attachments are named! Files with 164 bytes and 182 bytes are good in this small test... I hope you can solve your issue...

Comment: Please don't add this much inline code formatting to answers - it is not easy to read.

Comment: Ok. Is not a good reason for downvoting if my answer is useful. Anyway thanks for pointing me your think...